# RSS Feed - Parse/Extract src image tag inside Description tag in JAVA

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

Extending this question

[How to extract an image src from RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823042/how-to-extract-an-image-src-from-rss-feed)

for JAVA, answer is already made for ios, but to make it work in JAVA there is not enough solutions made for it.

RSS Feeds parsing the direct tag is known for me, but parsing tag inside another tag is quite complicated like this below

```
    <description>
    <![CDATA[
<img width="745" height="410" src="http://example.com/image.png" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="alt tag" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" />description text
    ]]>
    </description>
```

How to split up the src tag alone?

Comment: Negative voters please comment it

Comment: Quite demanding huh? There is an excellent developer guide from google on that topic.

Comment: Can u post that link? @MuratK.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). I think it's what you need.

**EDIT:**

```
private String extractImageUrl(String description) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(description);
    Elements imgs = document.select("img");

    for (Element img : imgs) {
        if (img.hasAttr("src")) {
            return img.attr("src");
        }
    }

    // no image URL
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Please read the question clearly, jsoup is meant for parsing only the html content, i asked for rss..

Comment: Please see my edit. That is the method I have use to extract the first-found-image inside RSS description element.

Comment: Fine Thanks, u are integrating Jsoup with rss, let me try it.

Comment: If it worked please mark as correct answer so it's visible to others. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, if you upvote the question also it will visible to users, since related to rss not many questions available.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a regular expression to get the value,
give a look to this little example, I hope it's help you.
For more info about regular expression you can find more info here. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String regularExpression = "src=\"(.*)\" class";
        String html = "<description> <![CDATA[ <img width=\"745\" height=\"410\" src=\"http://example.com/image.png\" class=\"attachment-large wp-post-image\" alt=\"alt tag\" style=\"margin-bottom: 15px;\" />description text ]]> </description>";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);


   if (matcher.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + matcher.group(1) );
        //It's prints Found value: http://example.com/image.png  
    }

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, anyway i already did with some splitting logics, i will try with this also

Comment: Excellent, this is another great way to get it done!